# How to get rid of a style attribute so my nivo slider will show up?

Tags: theming, javascript

I am using the Nivo Slider and for some reason it has a style attribute in its div tag that says

```
style="width: 0px";
```

I am trying to get rid of this so my slider will appear. I am not sure where this is coming from. I have CSS injector installed, but none of it makes a width: 0px and a grep search throughout the directories doesn't come up with one that will effect the outcome.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/node/229348 Gives a lot of good information on the subject.